# How do I link to the base View Folder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

In MVC, I am trying to link to a view directly in the View directory, the page is named "Settings.cshtml".  I have tried the following with no success:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Your Settings", "Settings", "View")
@Html.ActionLink("Your Settings", "Settings")
@Html.ActionLink("Your Settings", "Settings", "~/View")
```

Comment: Do you have Controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Action links do not link to a view, they link to an action. You will need to implement a controller action that returns the view:

```
public ActionResult Settings()
{
    return View();
}
```

If you place this in your `HomeController`, the following `ActionLink` should pick up your view:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Your Settings", "Settings")
```

If you need to do this a lot, you could look at implementing a more general Action method that allows you to pass in a view name, like so:

```
public ActionResult ShowView(string viewName)
{
    return View();
}
```

--

```
@Html.ActionLink("Your Settings", "ShowView", new { viewName = "Settings" })
```

Comment: Yup!  I thought it was linking to a View.  Thanks!